# Understanding memory caches in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm pretty new to C# and am trying to understand what the following method is doing, as a co worker I no longer work with it created it.

```cs
public static void setInventoryCache(string type, string att, int id, float val)
{
    string cacheKey = "inv-" + type + "-" + att + "-" + id.ToString();
    debugLog("set " + cacheKey + " = " + val);

    // expire cached items randomly so they don't all expire at the same time and need to be
    // re-cached
    int expire = random.Next(30, 90);
    CacheItemPolicy cip = new CacheItemPolicy
    {
        RemovedCallback = new CacheEntryRemovedCallback(removeCallBack),
        AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(expire),                    
    };

    InventoryCache.Set(cacheKey, val, cip);
}
```

It appears to me that the cache is is being told to expire every 30-90 minutes. Is this correct? Because in my program it seems to still grab old cached data, even if it over 90 minutes old

The problem I'm currently experiencing is my cache data is not equal to the data in my database, which it should be. This makes me think the data is not expiring properly. And why would the cached data be useful in the first place, why wouldn't just pulling data from the database be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `InventoryCache` is from Type `MemoryCache`.

The reason why the data is not expiring may, you're renewing the cache via calling `setInventoryCache` multiple times with the same cacheKey and data.

The reason why your data in the database and your cached data goes out of sync is by nature - it's a cache. So, you need to implement a mechanism that's refreshing/invalidating the cache, if data has changed. There's no general perfect way for that.

Of course, you can fetch the data always from the database without using the cache. It depends on how often you need the data and how often the data is changing, if it makes sense to use a cache or not.